# Unbind selectors in css file and after again bind selectors

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div and he has in file .css this selectors:

```
#item {background-image: url(Images/panda.png);
}
#item:hover { background-image: url(Images/pandaOf.png);
}
#item:active { background-image: url(Images/pandaOn.png);
}
```

And I need to (in jQuery) this selectors (:hover and :active) doesnt work.

```
$("#clickItem").click(function (){
...
 });
```

And after I need to this selectors again work.

```
$("#clickItem2").click(function (){
...
 });
```

HTML code:

```
<div id = "item"> </div>
<div id = "clickItem"> </div>
<div id = "clickItem2"> </div>
```

Comment: Wha?? Are `#clickItem` and `#clickItem2` the original `#item` div, but with a changed ID or extra elements? Does clicking those extra elements, enable/disable the css on `#item`? This question needs clarification

Comment: What do you need to do with these selectors in jQuery? Your question is not clear on that part.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID and then you can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()`

Comment: @Archer thank you. 
Sorry, I wrote this problem a little bit chaotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're getting at...

**CSS**

```
.item-active {
    background-image: url(Images/panda.png);
}
.item-active:hover {
    background-image: url(Images/pandaOf.png);
}
.item-active:active {
    background-image: url(Images/pandaOn.png);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="item" class="item-active"></div>
<div id="clickItem">clickItem</div>
<div id="clickItem2">clickItem2</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#clickItem").click(function (){
    $("#item").removeClass("item-active");
});

$("#clickItem2").click(function (){
    $("#item").addClass("item-active");
});
```

By default, you have the hover and active states for `#item`.  If you click `#clickItem` then it removes them.  If you click `#clickItem2` then it turns them back on again.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a specific hover method that could be useful to you.

Here is an example:

```
$("#clickItem").hover(function (){
      Code for OnHover goes here
 },
function (){
      Code for OffHover goes here
 }
});
```

Take a look at the jQuery hover documentation for more detail:
http://api.jquery.com/hover/